# Only fetch records with in date range

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have created below query :

```
SELECT 
UserID, Username,FirstName, LastName, SUM(CAST(Pass as SIGNED)) Pass,
 SUM(CAST(Fail as SIGNED)) Fail,SUM(CAST(Others as SIGNED))  Others, 
CAST(SUM(Pass+Fail+Others) as SIGNED)  TotalExecutions, CreatedDate 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT tbl_users.UserID, tbl_users.Username, tbl_users.FirstName, tbl_users.LastName, tbl_executionaudit.CreatedDate, 
    CASE WHEN tbl_executionaudit.Status ='5' THEN count(*) ELSE '' END as `Pass`, 
    CASE WHEN tbl_executionaudit.Status = '6' THEN count(*) ELSE '' END as `Fail`, 
    CASE WHEN tbl_executionaudit.Status !='5' and tbl_executionaudit.Status !='6'  THEN count(*) ELSE '' END as `Others` 
    FROM tbl_users 
    INNER JOIN tbl_useraccounts on tbl_users.UserID=tbl_useraccounts.UserID  
    INNER JOIN tbl_executionaudit on tbl_executionaudit.UserAccountID=tbl_useraccounts.UserAccountID 
    WHERE DATE(tbl_executionaudit.CreatedDate) BETWEEN '2019-06-15' AND '2019-08-30' or tbl_executionaudit.Status in(3,4,5,6,7,8) 
    GROUP by tbl_users.UserID, tbl_users.Username, tbl_executionaudit.Status, tbl_executionaudit.CreatedDate
) subquery 
GROUP BY UserID, Username
```

Query link : [external link to GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b3a2Gpz36vOOiNz0Lvnw-0La1cs0z-Ly/view)

I want to fetch from BETWEEN '2019-06-15' AND '2019-08-30' .

Comment: I only want to fetch records within date range while no other data will show from that range as you can see in the attached image

Comment: Use `AND` in WHERE ckause instead of `OR`...

Comment: createdate is the starting and ending date as well for my scenario.

Comment: *WHERE DATE(tbl_executionaudit.CreatedDate) BETWEEN '2019-06-15' AND '2019-08-30' **or** tbl_executionaudit.Status in(3,4,5,6,7,8)* - error marked.

Comment: actually i cant use 'or' in my scenario because i'm fetching all the status from 3 to 8.

Comment: Try firstly, please. I'd like to see "The result is wrong" instead of "I can't"...

Comment: Got same result after adding 'or'.

Comment: i dont want to show last 5 records from attached image .
after adding 'or' i got last 5 as well that i dont want.